# Floating LVDS Input

Tags: fpga, signal-integrity, lvds

I am designing a FPGA based receiver for a specific IC, which communicates its data utilizing standard LVDS interface with 100 Ohm termination resistors.

The IC has 10 channels (pairs) plus the clock. Depending on the mode of operation, not all of them are utilized, and, according to the datasheet, the unused ones enter in high-impedance state. I have designed my receiver in such a way that all channels are sampled every time but only the valid ones are processed according to the mode of operations (so in mode 1, only the first 2 channels are taken into account, if mode 2, the first 4, etc).

After some thinking, I started to be concerned about the floating inputs. Since those pairs are not biased in any way and are left totally floating yet sampled as usual, could this cause any problems/instabilities to the receiver?

Comment: Sure, it might cause problems. But what does the FPGA datasheet say about this, and is there internal bias circuitry to make unconnected pins to float at some defined stable state?

Comment: @Justme After much studying of the datasheet and technical notes I could not find a reference that address this scenario (floating LVDS) directly or implies that there is a failsafe mechanism. The only recommendation I could find was to not left pins floating as they increase power consumption. For single ended I/Os there is the option to use pullup/pulldown resistors. Since I am using the internal termination resistors for the LVDS reception, there might be some consideration to add bias. If I read the output of a floating LVDS input and is constant, could this mean it is biased internally?